# How to Vote / Like comments using YouTube .NET API?

Tags: c#, api, youtube

I am making a YouTube Automation Application using YouTube and Google .NET APIs. But could'nt find the way to vote up / down video comments using API. Please help in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Support for likes/dislikes hasn't been added to the .NET client
library yet. In the meantime, the underlying Atom XML element
corresponding to the rating request is documented at

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:rating